# Как правильно отобразить datagridview в pdf c помощью iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itextsharp

По этому мануала пытался настроить [мануал iTextSharp.](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-Windows-Forms-DataGridView-to-PDF-using-iTextSharp-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Столкнулся с тем, что мой datagridview[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отображается в PDF [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему он пропускает два столбца с информацией?

```
    SqlDataAdapter adapt;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayData();
    }

    private void DisplayData()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from posts", con);
        adapt.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }


    private void btnExportPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
        PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.ColumnCount);

        //Adding Header row
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
            cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(240, 240, 240);
            pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
        }

        //Adding DataRow
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString());
            }
        }

        //Exporting to PDF
        string folderPath = "C:\\PDFs\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
        }
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folderPath + "DataGridViewExport.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Код только добавляет номера и знаки препинания в документ. Это ключ к решению этой проблемы.

Вы никогда не указывали шрифт в коде. Если шрифт не указан, будет использоваться шрифт по умолчанию. По умолчанию используется шрифт Helvetica. Гельветика не имеет символы для символы, которые вы пытаетесь представить.

Всякий раз, когда iText встречает текст, который он не в состоянии представить в шрифте вы хотите, он будет просто пропустить их.

Вот почему ваши клетки не имеют содержания в них.

Решение здесь-установить шрифт.

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/tutorial/using-fonts-pdf-and-itext